# Django: поля inline формы в шаблоне

Tags: django

Подскажите как изменить стандартный вывод полей inline-формы.

```
FormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(Entertainment, EntertainmentCollage, fields =['img',], extra=1)
```

Сейчас в шаблоне

```
{{ form2.management_form }}  
{% for frm in form2 %}
  {{ frm.as_p }}
{% endfor %}
```

В результате получаю такой вид:

[image]

Как избавиться от лишнего и получить только кнопку с надписью Add photo

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо изменить виджет для файлового поля. Это можно сделать передав в `inlineformset_factory` виджет явно:

```
FormSet2 = Entertainment, EntertainmentCollage, fields =['img',], extra=1, widgets={
    'img': forms.FileInput(),
})
```

По умолчанию, django использует виджет [ClearableFileInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput).

Comment: Как не странно, внешний вид не поменялся.